# Perl and PDF::API2: ttfont() does not work

Tags: pdf-generation, truetype

I used to set my PDF::API2 fonts like this in my Perl script, it worked fine:

```
$font{'h'}  = $p->corefont( "Helvetica" );
```

Then when I wanted to print unicode characters (Russian Cyrillic characters) it did not work. I found out, that you have to use TrueType fonts and then all these special characters would work. So I tried this:

```
$font{'h'} = $pdf->ttfont('times.ttf');
```

Before I copied the file 'times.ttf' from my Windows font directory to any directory where PDF::API2 could be looking: The directory where my script is located, the directory where PDF::API2 is located, and several other directories. But I always got an "Internal Server Error" message. The script runs on a Linux server. I also tried that:

```
$font{'h'} = $pdf->ttfont('external_ttfs/times.ttf');
```

(I created 'external_ttfs' before as a sub directory of PDF::API2's "PDF" directory. It did not work either. I thought maybe the problem could be the "times.ttf" file, it might not have the correct format. So I downloaded "DejaVuSans.ttf", a free font. I copied also this file to various directories of my webspace. But also this command caused the internal server error:

```
$font{'h'} = $pdf->ttfont('DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be the problem? Thank you in advance! I don't have a clue if the TTF file is not correct, if it cannot be found, or if there is any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib 'PDF-API2-0.73/lib/';


use PDF::API2;

my $text = "A sample text using Noto TTF";

my $pdf  = PDF::API2->new();
my $page = $pdf->page;
my $txt = $page->text;

my $font = $pdf->ttfont('C:/temp/fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf');        

$txt->font($font, 25);
$txt->translate(200, 550);
$txt->fillcolor('black');
$txt->text($text);

$pdf->saveas("Noto-TTF.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you install the Font:TTF module on Perl?
Download it from [here](http://search.cpan.org/~mhosken/Font-TTF-1.05/lib/Font/TTF.pm) and add it to Perl lib folder then retry.